# android application to upload an image file to localhost

Tags: android, localhost

```
 07-24 09:43:44.198: E/Upload file to server Exception(8298): Exception : 
 failed to  connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
 07-24 09:43:44.198: E/Upload file to server Exception(8298): java.net.ConnectException:                   

    failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection   refused)
```

i tried android application to upload an image file to localhost(UBUNTU).when i try this i get above error

Comment: Can you show your codes? Also, please double check your port is not blocked.

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106

Answer (score 3):

**use the IP address** `10.0.2.2` **instead of** `127.0.0.1`